# Question about force on cable of varying density

Tags: calculus, integration

My math teacher have us a question:

A non-uniform cable of length 20 feet gets thicker toward the bottom.The density of the cable x feet above the bottom is 20-x pounds per foot.The cable is hanging heavy-end down off a high cliff.How much work is needed to pull the cable to the top of the cliff?

I tried to find out how to do this, but could only find how to do questions like this when the density is constant.

Does anybody know how to do this question, or varying density questions?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches, which better give the same answer as they are solving the same problem.

The force to lift the cable is just the weight below the cliff.  If the linear density is a constant $\rho$, the weight is just $\rho$ times the length.  If the linear density is $\rho(x)$ and varies with $x$, you need to integrate.  The total weight is $\int \rho dx$.  If you let $x=0$ be the bottom of the cable, you integrate from $0$ to $x$ at any given time.  The work you do in lifting the cable a distance $dx$ is then $mg\; dx=g\int_0^x\rho dx$.  Adding up the work over the whole run gives $\int_0^{20}g\int_0^x\rho\;dx\;dx$

The other approach is to ask how much work it takes to lift each bit of mass to the cliff top.  The bit between $x$ and $x+dx$ has a mass $\rho(x)dx$.  It has to get lifted $20-x$ feet, so the work is $\rho dx g(20-x)$ and the total work is $\int_0^{20}\rho  g(20-x)\;dx$

The second will be easier this time, but I think it is important to understand both approaches.  The first may be easier next time.